# I have created exe file using py2exe, I Need to bundle all dependency files into single exe to improve portability.How canI do that?

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I have created `.exe` file using py2exe, I Need to bundle all dependency files into single exe to improve portability.

How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

I have tried this code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    console = [{'script': script_file}]
)
```

But `library.zip` file & `w9xpopen.exe` files are still existing in the dist folder, while generating .exe I am getting following warning:

`unknown distribution option Zipfile while using py2exe`.

Is this this reason why all the files are not included in my exe??

I am doing this in:

```
Windows 7 32 bit.
Python version 2.7.3
py2exe version 0.6.9.
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this:

```
options = {'py2exe': {
       'compressed':1,  
       'bundle_files': 2, 
       'dist_dir': "my/dist/dir"
       }}
setup(console=['main.py'], options=options)
```

and it has always worked out as it should

when typing in console C:\python27> python setup.py py2exe